Binary/dichotomous variables in random-intercept crossed-lagged panel models (RI-CLPM)
I would like to implement a RI-CLPM model in lavaan, but I am having some issues, which I suspect are related to having one variable being dichotomous (binary) and how this is accounted for in terms of random intercept.
Here is some simulated data:
set.seed(123)

n <- 500

Y1 <- rnorm(n)
X1_prob <- 1 / (1 + exp(-(0.5 + 0.05*Y1))) 
X1 <- rbinom(n, 1, X1_prob)

Y2 <- 0.5*Y1 + rnorm(n) + 0.25*X1 -0.5
X2_prob <- 1 / (1 + exp(-(0.5  + 0.25*Y2 + 0.05*Y1))) 
X2 <- rbinom(n, 1, X2_prob)

data <- data.frame(
  X1 = X1, 
  X2 = X2,
  Y1 = Y1, 
  Y2 = Y2
)

data$X1 <- as.factor(data$X1)
data$X2 <- as.factor(data$X2)

I am fairly new to lavaan, but if my understanding of the syntax is correct, the model should be defined as follow:
clpm_model_ri <- '
  # Random intercepts
  ri_X =~ 1*X1 + 1*X2
  ri_Y =~ 1*Y1 + 1*Y2

  # Regressions (cross-lagged effects)
  X2 ~ X1 + Y1
  Y2 ~ Y1 + X1

  # Covariances
  X1 ~~ Y1
  X2 ~~ Y2
  ri_X ~~ ri_Y

  # Residual variances
  Y1 ~~ Y1
  Y2 ~~ Y2
'

However, I am having troubles with estimation. I run the model as:
fit_clpm_ri <- lavaan::sem(clpm_model_ri, data = data, ordered = c("X1", "X2"), estimator = "WLSMV")

but receive this error
Warning message:
lavaan->lav_model_vcov():  
   Could not compute standard errors! The information matrix could 
   not be inverted. This may be a symptom that the model is not 
   identified. 

Am I doing something wrong? if I run a simple CLPM, without random intercept, everything seems to work fine, and I have standard errors and p-values in the output.
I searched other questions but could not find anything directly relevant. I have tried to tweak the code in various ways, but no success so far. Any suggestions or pointer to relevant tutorials and examples is appreciated! 

Do you mean RI-CLPM, or CLPM? Your example data only has two waves, RI-CLPM needs at minimum 3 waves. Your error reflects that you are trying to define more model parameters than you have data for. Some good RI-CLPM tutorials include https://jochemtolsma.github.io/RI-CLPM/lavaan.html & https://johnflournoy.science/riclpmr/articles/riclpmr.html

That was indeed the issue, thanks! I eventually figure it out after spending some more time learning lavaan syntax
